# Jquery : How can I apply a class to li containing a link with specific id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am stuck trying to apply a class to a surrounding list element based on the id of the link element contained inside  :

```
var itemId = 1; // set itemid from current url 

var tabId = 'tab'+itemId; // set tabid based on itemid e.g a#tab1, a#tab2 ...

 // add class selected to li containing tabid

$("#tabs ul li").each(function(){

    $(this).has("a#" + tabId + "").addClass("selected");

});
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var tabId = "tab1";
$("#tabs ul li:has(a#"+tabId+")").addClass("selected");
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/f6nPx/

A faster way to do (almost) the same thing

```
$("#"+tabId).closest("li").addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

find your element, then go up by using the closest function. 
An example is on the [closest api page](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)